# Issue with creating symbolic link to directory in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, symlink

I am trying to create a symbolic link from one folder to another in C# net472 without success. Here is my current code :

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, SymbolicLink dwFlags);

private enum SymbolicLink
{
    File = 0,
    Directory = 1
}

var source = @"C:\.test";
var destination = @"C:\destinationTest";

CreateSymbolicLink(source, destination, SymbolicLink.Directory);
```

And nothing really happens to either folder. The method returns false. I'm already running visual studio in admin mode

Comment: Full administrator rights are required for this to work - if you don't have that the function return true regardless - see this http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateSymbolicLink

Comment: Thank you for the link, I learned how to print the error and turns out I wasn't supposed to have `C:\.test` already created. I deleted and it works now

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong order for the arguments:

```
CreateSymbolicLink(source, destination, SymbolicLink.Directory);
```

Run the following instead, and as an admin:

```
CreateSymbolicLink(destination, source, SymbolicLink.Directory);
```

```
public static bool IsRunningAsAdmin()
{
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);

        return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
    //for mac and linux
    return true;
    
}
```

---

And this will do as well:

```
   FileSystemInfo fileSymLink = File.CreateSymbolicLink(destFileName, sourceFileName);
```